# laravel 5 update in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created a row in my 'movies' table called 'slug' where i want to store the slug of the titles of my movies.the problem is i already have 250 movies and i don't want to manually enter the slug to each one of them so i am trying to make a script to automatically update all the slugs.But i failed to do that:

This is my code in FilmController.php:

```
class FilmController extends Controller {

public function film()

  {
    $title = DB::table('movies')->select('title');
    $slug = str_replace(" ","-",$title);
    DB::table('movies')->update(array('slug' => $slug));
  }
}
```

And this is in my routes:

```
Route::get('update','FilmController@film');
```

This is the error that pops up when i go to localhost/update:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string

Can somebody tell me how could i change my code so i can put in my slug field in all the movies the title of the movie with '-' insted of space between the words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$title is an object containing all titles, and not a string,so str_replace will not work on it
you can try using a loop to update each record according to its title

something like

```
$titles = DB::table('movies')->select('title','id')->get();
foreach ($titles as $title){
     $slug = str_replace(" ","-",$title->title);
     DB::table('movies')->where('id',$title->id)->update(array('slug' => $slug));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend use a `seeder` if you want to make a script that update or create default info on your database.
[Laravel Database Seeding doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#database-seeding)

And `title` have a collection of titles not a single title.